# Como estruturar um bom controller com Laravel Socialite?

Tags: laravel

Estou utilizando o **Socialite** para prover autenticação via provedores de conta (Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn...).

Na minha aplicação, ao realizar autenticação via provedor, se já existir uma associação da conta atual do usuário com a conta do provedor ele será logado, se não existir vinculo atual com a conta do provedor, será feita uma associação com o cadastro atual, caso não tenha cadastro o mesmo será criado (usuário redirecionado para uma view com a finalidade de confirmar somente seu nome).

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('auth-socialite/{provider}', 'Auth\SocialiteController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth-socialite/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\SocialiteController@handleProviderCallback');
Route::post('auth-socialite/criar-usuario', 'Auth\SocialiteController@createUser');
```

SocialiteController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Auth;
use Socialite;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\ProvedoresServicoContas;

class SocialiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Endereço para onde o usuário será redirecionado após o login
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Chama a página de autenticação do provedor (Facebook, Linkedin, Twitter...)
     *
     * @param $provedor
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function redirectToProvider($provedor)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provedor)->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Autentica o usuário via callback do provedor (Facebook, Linkedin, Twitter...)
     *
     * @param $provedor
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback($provedor)
    {
        $userProvedor = Socialite::driver($provedor)->user();

        $authUsuario = $this->findOrCreateUser($userProvedor, $provedor);

        if (!$authUsuario)
            return view('auth.socialite-novo-user', compact('userProvedor', 'provedor'));

        Auth::login($authUsuario, true);

        return redirect($this->redirectTo);
    }

    /**
     * Se o usuário já existe o mesmo será retornado, do contrário será criado
     *
     * @param $userProvedor
     * @param $provedor
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    public function findOrCreateUser($userProvedor, $provedor)
    {
        $conta = ProvedoresServicoContas::whereProvedor($provedor)
            ->whereProvedorUserId($userProvedor->getId())
            ->first();

        if ($conta)
            return $conta->user;

        $usuario = User::whereEmail($userProvedor->getEmail())->first();

        if (!$usuario) {
            session(['userProvedor' => $userProvedor, 'provedor' => $provedor]);
            return false;
        }

        return $this->associarProvedorUsuario($usuario, $userProvedor, $provedor);
    }

    public function createUser(Request $request)
    {
        $userProvedor = session('userProvedor');
        $provedor = session('provedor');

        $usuario = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $userProvedor->email,
            'password' => bcrypt(str_random(20)),
        ]);

        $this->associarProvedorUsuario($usuario, $userProvedor, $provedor);

        Auth::login($usuario, true);

        return redirect($this->redirectTo);
    }

    public function associarProvedorUsuario($usuario, $userProvedor, $provedor)
    {
        $criarConta = new ProvedoresServicoContas([
            'provedor_user_id' => $userProvedor->getId(),
            'provedor' => $provedor
        ]);

        $criarConta->user()->associate($usuario);
        $criarConta->save();

        return $usuario;
    }
}
```

migrate:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProvedoresServicoContasTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.


 *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('provedores_servico_contas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('provedor');
            $table->string('provedor_user_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('provedores_servico_contas');
    }
}
```

Atualmente esta funcionando, porém, acho que meu controller esta confuso. Alguma sugestão de melhoria em termos de organização e eficiência?

Answer (score -2):

Tente separar em [camadas de responsabilidade](https://m.dotdev.co/design-pattern-service-layer-with-laravel-5-740ff0a7b65f) .

Deixe o controller apenas recebendo a requisição da view e repassando o conteúdo processado. Crie services com toda lógica de negócio encapsulado, tratando erros de negócio, validações, etc.
Também sugiro que crie repositórios que devem ser responsáveis por interpretar o que é lido e formatar a saída dos dados de forma a fazer sentido para o negócio, nunca objetos sem definição, como JSONs ou DTOs.

Criando as camadas, de início, dá um trabalhinho mas fica bem mais organizado e mais fácil de manter.